# Не получается назначить класс

Tags: css

```
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://image.ibb.co/dHEYSK/montaj.jpg" alt="First slide">

                        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                            <h5>Качественный монтаж канализаций!</h5>
                            <p>Сделаем все в сроки быстро и качественно/p>
                        </div>
```

Не получает назначит классы делаю так :

```
.carousel-caption .d-none .d-md-block {
font-size:20px;
```

}

Пробовал еще так:

```
carousel-caption .d-none .d-md-block p h5 {
font-size:20px;
```

}

Answer (score 5):

Классы одного элемента должны идти без разделителей (пробелов):

```
.carousel-caption.d-none.d-md-block {
  font-size:20px;    
}
```

Пробелами разделяются классы вложенных элементов.

Comment: то есть это все тоже самое , просто без пробелов ?

Comment: @AlexanderKozin да, правильно

Comment: блин , вроде бы мелочь а из за нее ничего не получалось , спасибо тебе огромное)

Comment: @AlexanderKozin Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.